# Why does an anonymous user stay anonymous after successfully calling sendEmailVerification?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Using the Javascript Firebase SDK I essentially do this:

```
// do the signIn
firebase.signInAnonymously()
console.lof(user.isAnonymous) // obviously: true

// determine email and send it to anon user
user.updateEmail(somebody@example.com)
user.sendEmailVerification()

// after I reload the user
user.reload()
console.log(user.emailVerified) // true
console.lof(user.isAnonymous) // false
```

Why does the user remain anonymous although he successfully went through verification. What would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Not sure I got correctly your question, are you trying to upgrade from anonymous user to a user with credentials? If so try the last point here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth

Comment: I am aware. Unfortunately this wont help me since the anon user is session (aka tab) specific. I do not know how the anon user and authcred from signinWithEmail could be available in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous users can't be verified directly.  The point of an anonymous account is so that the user can have an account without requiring the user to give up their identity.  Since anonymous accounts don't have an email address, it's meaningless to require an email verification.  You might want to check to see if there was an error during that call (you should always check to see if the returned promise was resolved successfully or rejected with an error).

If you want to cover the anonymous account into an email/password account that **can** be verified, [follow the instructions in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account).  You will end up having to call `linkWithCredential` to finalize the covnersion.

Comment: It is my point exactly that if you given an anon user an email and verify it you would expect an automatic upgrade (and isAnonymous === true). `linkWithCredential` is not feasible in my case because of the differing auth flow.

Comment: Sorry, that's just not the way it works.  If you have a feature request for Firebase Authentication, you can file it with Firebase support. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support